# How can I display all images - those included with the app and on the sdcard?

Tags: android

I want the user to be able to select from ALL images - those included with my app aswell as any they may have on their sdcard.  For example, I have a .jpg file called cat.jpg in the data/com.mypackage/files folder, but it will not show in the list of images.  This is the code I used, but it only displays images on the sdcard:

```
  // Open up a gallery browser
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
```

I know that  I could have two screens, one showing my images and another showing those from the sdcard, but I would rather have all of pictures in one gallery list.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

update:
Since no one has responsed, then maybe this type of task just can't be done.  I cannot find any documentation one way or the other.  If someone knows where the gallery view gets its data, please let me know (docs just says images - not the source of them).  Or if it is not possible to combine all images from both the phone and the sdcard in one display, I would appreciate that response also.

Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately the gallery app will only parse your SD card for images.  The images included with your app in /data are on the phone's internal memory and can't be seen by the gallery app.

You wouldn't be able to display them all in one place easily :-\

Comment: Thank you soooo much.  I will now put that option down and move on. :)